# How to open the terminal in Ubuntu and passe parameters to it by using Java code?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu and I just want to open the terminal from Java and execute this command `make iris sim`. After that keep the terminal open until the user click any key.

This is my code, but it's not working correctly:

```
String []commands= {"make", "iris", "sim"};
String[] cmdArray = {"/usr/bin/xterm", "-e"};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray, commands);
```

Comment: What means "it's not working correctly"?

Comment: its not executed and no errors..

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish what you want using a shell script instead of Java?

Comment: That is only small part of my project, since all the project is being built by using Java.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665483/java-cannot-execute-system-command-ubuntu

Comment: Thank you so much for this link, but i dont know how to make a shell file with my command in order to call it from Java.

Comment: To learn file IO, you can use the tutorial at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html

Comment: My problem is not the files, it's in passing parameters to the terminal by using Java in Ubuntu environment..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the exec command wrong. The second parameter is not an array of "commands" but an array of environment variables. See the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

Instead, simply call your command:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/xterm -e make iris sim");
```

Note that this will create a new process. If you want to wait for this process call `p.waitFor();`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did exactly what you said but it's also not working. Actually it works if I change the command( e.g. `gedit filename.txt`), but `make iris sim` command is not executed ...